# SQL DACPAC ERROR - sqlpackage.exe - p:ExtractAllTableData option invalid

Tags: sql-server, dacpac

I am running a utility which uses SQL DAC PAC to generate the scripts.

```
sqlpackage.exe /scs:"server=DBServer;uid=uname;pwd=pwd;database=DBToExtract" /tf:"1.dacpac" 
/Action:Extract /p:ExtractAllTableData=true /p:IgnorePermissions=false
```

I am getting an error **"'ExtractAllTableData'** is not a valid argument for the **'Extract'** action." Not sure why the option is invalid. Have tried with the data tools available in **SQL Server 2012**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this command using the latest version of SqlPackage.exe, which can be downloaded by itself here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53876

Or with the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I remember by default it is true and if you are not providing that parameter then it extracts all tables, But if you have requirement on specifying individual tables then we need to explicitly provide 'ExtractAllTableData' as false and provide TableData..